# How to create realistic grass displacement or grass areas

Tags: modeling, rendering, texturing

I am trying to recreate the scene shown in this video: https://youtu.be/LsdpKXD_2hM?t=99 (with timecode).

You can see, there are pathways and grass areas. I already have recreate the main scene, but I struggle with the vegetation part. I can't understand, how they did the grass displacement part as seen in the video? Did they placed them or is this just a texture with some displacement maps?

In the screenshot below I will provide you my current status of this scene: [image]

I have used an RGB seperate node to create this ground map from an PNG image of the actual launchpad. But how can I now place the grass there? Should I use a displacement texture or some actuall grass clumps? Or is this displacement like in the video, some rendering trickery?

I am aiming for the same result like in the video, but I don't know what can I do to enhance my scene to make it more realistic?

I would appreciate some help from the community. :)
in this screenshot, you can see, that I already have the pathways created: [image]

Comment: hello, you could use a b&w map to separate the grass from the road, and for the grass, as it's pretty far from the camera, just use a Noise Texture plugged into a ColorRamp with 2 greens?

Comment: but that will not have any displacement going on.. as you can see it in the video..

Comment: i don't see a lot of dispacement but you can fake displacement with a Noise Texture plugged into a Bump node?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a try of material: Basically it is a mix (*MixRGB* in *Multiply* mode) between 2 *Noise* to create 2 levels of details, and a bit of *Bump* to create fake 3D relief:

[image]

You can use a b&w image as factor in a *Mix Shader* to create the road: Here to keep it simple I've just plugged a *Diffuse* in the other input but of course it also needs noise and bump:

[image]

Comment: B&W mask - where should I pluck it into? into the mixRGB node? or where?

Comment: I've edited my answer, I hope it helps @raytracin'_02

Comment: Thank you for your help! 
It starts to look nice. But in the video, they have used probably actual grass clumps.. because you can see there much more details. Your attempt does give good results, but it looks flat.. I don't know if it can be improved :) 

But thanks again, for your help.

Comment: in that case use a particle system?